# Upgrade drupal from version 7 to version 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I tried to upgrade from Opigno LMS 1.38 to Opigno LMS 2.3

it's concerning to upgrade from drupal 7 to Drupal 8

I got this error at the upgrade page :

"The video plugin must define the source_module property."

Please, could someone help me ?

I followed this steps to run the upgrade :

*Step 2: Activate contrib modules for migration in Drupal 8 on page /admin/modules:
Migrate
Migrate Drupal
Migrate Drupal UI
Migrate Plus
Migrate Tools

Step 3: Activate custom module for migration in Drupal 8 on page /admin/modules:

Opigno Migration

Step 4: Add connection to the legacy base (Drupal 7) with target ‘default’ and key ‘legacy’ in your settings.php file.

```
Example
$databases['legacy']['default']= array(
'database' => 'opigno_drupal7',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'root',
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '',
'driver' => 'mysql',
'prefix' => '',
);
```

Step 5: Open page /upgrade on your Drupal 8 site and click on button ‘Continue’.*

I got the error after the step 5

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you run the upgrade (which tool) ? What did you try so far ? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In case others are struggling, the video contrib module needs this patch to play nicely with migrate
Apply the patch in https://www.drupal.org/project/video/issues/2986682